# Removing Rows from CSV file with conditional argument Python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove rows with Python in a CSV file from a specific column with conditional argument. from example, deleting all the rows from that column that are between 3 different intervals. for example 99 and 1000, 5000 and 6000, 8000 and 9000.

Comment: Can you give some sample input and desired sample output?

Comment: Yes. so the file is open already on jupyter notebook, there is a Column called SICCD that i need to delete the rows of this column that contains the values in the range 0100-0999, 9100-9729, 9990-9999.

Comment: Can you put a sample of your file (or something that looks like it) in the question?

Comment: I answered your question below. Would you mind upvoting my answer? I'm new here and it would help me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file, filter the rows out and and write results to a new csv.

```
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('output.csv', 'wb') as out:
interval = [range(99, 1001), range(5000, 6001), range(8000, 9001)]
writer = csv.writer(out)
for row in csv.reader(inp):
     if row["column_name"] not in interval:
         writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: use dict instead of lists. 
This whole method you have is not efficient.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb Did you flag this as a low quality post? I think my approach is pretty clear.

Comment: Who flagged it does not matter. Your approach is code only which is generally considered not a good answer. Answers need explanations as to why you answered it the way you did so that you can help the person asking the question and anyone in the future that may not understand the code as well as you do.

Comment: It’s generally recommended to put all of the information needed into the answer not only for OP but for future people that have a similar question. Comments are helpful for the person asking but are often harder to understand than edited the answer to provide everything needed in one place. Just like you could have down voted him instead of answering, I could have deleted your answer instead of commenting to let you know how not to get flagged in the future. Everyone is here because they need help or want to help. It’s good to answer questions at all, but it’s better to document them well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

cmd = "sed -e '5000,6000d;99,1000d' file.csv"
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: OP did not specify their operating system

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your intervals using `range`, and checking if an item is `in` a `range` is quite quick:

```py
import csv

# add 1 to the max of the range for an inclusive search
intervals = [range(99, 1001), range(5000, 6001), range(8000, 9001)]

with open('data.csv') as fh, with open('out.csv', 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        # do this to avoid the constant lookup of row['column_name']
        # in the interval check
        col = row['column_name']

        # it's fast to check if an integer is in a range
        # use all to check for each range
        if all(col not in i for i in intervals):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

To show the difference between checking in a `list`:

### range check

```py
python -m timeit -s 'x = 10000; y = range(10002)' 'x in y'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0821 usec per loop
```

### list check

```py
python -m timeit -s 'x = 10000; y = list(range(10002))' 'x in y'
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.4 usec per loop
```